# Thymeleaf inline JavaScript is completely ignored

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I'm trying to include a basic vanilla JS script into a Thymeleaf view but it seems to be completely ignored - I don't even see it when I inspect the page. I assume the issue is related with the fact that the view is part of a layout template but I cannot figure out where the problem is.

The View:

```
<!doctype html>
<html th:replace="~{fragments/layout :: layout(~{::title}, ~{}, ~{}, ~{::main})}">
    <head>
        <title>Reports Page</title>
    </head>     
    <body>
        <main role="main" class="flex-shrink-0">
            <!-- some HTML code here -->
            <select class="form-select" id="year" aria-label="Year dropdown" th:onchange="reloadPage()">
                <option 
                    th:each="yearRow : ${years}" 
                    th:value="${yearRow}" 
                    th:selected="(${yearRow} == ${year})"
                    th:text="${yearRow}">
                </option>
            </select>
            <!-- other HTML code here -->
        </main>

        <script th:inline="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function reloadPage() {
                alert("You selected a year");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The Layout fragment:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="h-100" th:fragment="layout (title, css_assets, js_assets, content)" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <!-- Usual head stuff - meta tags, links to Bootstrap CSS & fonts libraries etc -->
    <!-- Common CSS Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/styles.css}">
    
    <!-- Per-page placeholder for additional links -->
    <th:block th:replace="${css_assets}" />
        
    <title th:replace="${title}">Layout Title</title>
</head>
<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
    <header th:replace="~{fragments/header :: header}"></header>
   
    <div th:replace="${content}">
        <p>Layout content</p>
    </div>
       
    <footer th:replace="~{fragments/footer :: footer}"></footer>
    
    <!-- Common scripts -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!-- Per-page placeholder for additional scripts -->
    <th:block th:replace="${js_assets}" />
</body>
</html>
```

Inspecting the code, I don't see the inline script:

[image]

.. and in the console the Javascript function is not found:
[image]

Of course, probably I can use the ${js_assets} to inject my JS function from an external JS file but it bothers me why is it not working with  the inline syntax. Am I missing something?

I'm pretty new to Spring Boot and Thymeleaf so please be understanding. Thanks!

Comment: In your view, the `th:replace` is part of the top-level `<html>` tag - so everything inside that tag (all child tags) get replaced by the layout fragment - including the script containing `reloadPage()`. You probably need to use more targeted fragments, which can be used to replace more targeted sections of your view. That way, you can ensure that the `<script>` tag which contains your `reloadPage()` function is not replaced. Using `<div th:replace...>` sections is one way to control this.

Comment: @andrewJames: Somehow I thought that there will be some kind of intersection between the code in the layout, fragments and view. I added the solution I ended up with as an answer based on your feedback. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [andrewJames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75792513/thymeleaf-inline-javascript-is-completely-ignored/75793511#comment133698145_75792513) I realized that the only HTML code that gets injected from my view into the final HTML is the one included between the *main* tags - everything else that is not a fragment in the layout is replaced. The easiest fix would have been to include my inline script inside main.

But since I want to have it right before the closing body tag I ended up leveraging the placeholder I already built into my layout for page-by-page JS.

Here's the new code for view (notice that the parameter for js_assets sent in the layout is pointing now to the fragment in the page)

```
<!doctype html>
<html th:replace="~{fragments/layout :: layout(~{::title}, ~{}, ~{::js_assets}, ~{::main})}">
    <head>
        <title>Reports Page</title>
    </head>     
    <body>
        <main role="main" class="flex-shrink-0">
            <!-- some HTML code here -->
            <select class="form-select" id="year" aria-label="Year dropdown" th:onchange="reloadPage()">
                <option 
                    th:each="yearRow : ${years}" 
                    th:value="${yearRow}" 
                    th:selected="(${yearRow} == ${year})"
                    th:text="${yearRow}">
                </option>
            </select>
            <!-- other HTML code here -->
        </main>

        <th:block th:fragment="js_assets">
            <script th:inline="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                function reloadPage() {
                    alert("You selected a year");
                }
            </script>
        </th:block>
    </body>
</html>
```